# Asynchronous call blocking mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a grid in which every row is having a button , clicking on the button start async process and insert some record in the database of mysql

When i clicked another button on the grid without finishing the first call, the whole thing stopped working and page throwing error even when i launch it again

Error Message

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'

It is stuck in the endless loop and whole server from my application is blocked, even from my local server it is not working

button click button

```
protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadButton btn = sender as RadButton;
        
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await RunAsync(btn, num, int.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString()));
        btn.Enabled = true;
        btn.ToolTip = "Job Complete";
    });
}    

public async Task RunAsync(RadButton btnRn, int batch, int userId)
{

    RadButton btn = btnRn as RadButton;
    string hwid = btn.CommandArgument;
    if (hwid != null && hwid != string.Empty)
    {
        //all 
        IEnumerable<CaseDetails> lstFilterHwList = lstCaseFiltered.Where(f => f.HWID == int.Parse(hwid)).ToList();
        lstJobs = lstJobs.Where(f => f.HWID == int.Parse(hwid) && f.StatusName.ToUpper() != "DONE").ToList();
        lstFilterHwList = lstFilterHwList.Where(f => !lstJobs.Any(lk => lk.JobContent == f.CaseID)).ToList();
        
        if (lstFilterHwList.Count() > 0)
        {

            foreach (CaseDetails caseDetail in lstFilterHwList)
            {

               
             
                if (printer != null)
                {
                    
                    //Station station = deviceRepository.GetStation(stationLocation);
                    if (station != null)
                    {
                        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            JobContent content = new JobContent();
                            content.JobName = "TDMSID_" + tdmsCase.TestCaseId;
                            content.JobFrom = "TED";
                            // Logger.WriteMessageToLog_AutoExcute("HwID" + printer.HWID);
                            content.HwId = printer.HWID;
                            content.Firmware = caseDetail.Firmware;
                            content.PrinterIP = printer.ADDRESS;
                           
                            content.MachineIP = station.StationIP;
                            content.MachineTypeID = "1";
                            content.userId =  tdmsUser.ZCATUID; //userId;//tdmsUser.ZCATUID;
                            content.ProjectId = 0;
                            content.ToolName = "ZCAT Plus";
                            content.AutomationId = caseDetail.CaseID.ToString();
                            content.DatabaseServer = "Test";
                            content.BatchID = batch;
                            string apiUrl = string.Empty;
                            
                            apiUrl = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/api/Jobs";
                            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, CreateHttpContent<JobContent>(content));
                            //response.StatusCode
                            // response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                          

                        }

                    }
                   

                    
                }
               
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the mysql related part? Part of the code is missing here

Comment: You have several problems here, even without the rest of the code. 1 you are offloading to the thread-pool so you dont have to propagate the async and await pattern, secondly. since you are offloading you are on another thread trying to access a UI component. lastly, you are using `Task.Factory.StartNew` where there are only limited use cases in modern .net , you should always prefer `Task.Run`

Comment: The timeout is most likely caused by your SQL, also who knows what `RunAsync` does

Comment: its good that you have added more code, but oh my... I think you need to take a step back and work on this a little at a time, there is a lot to go wrong here. and a remote service...

Comment: Can you please help me by explaining in detail , i added more details right now error comes when try to fill the dataset
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds); //error coming from this line

Comment: can someone help me how to correct the mistakes

Comment: You are getting a sql timeout exception, however you have included no sql. The query is taking too long, what does this query do?

Comment: Query is to read data and api m using to save data but when m executing the read procedure on work bench in gives me time error , when I tried killing the process it is not letting me

Comment: Even a simple select statement not work for those tables

Comment: I observed that it happened when I clicked another button before finishing first async call , do I need to maintain multithreads , if yes then how

Comment: The only suggest/issue here is the routine you want to thread is NOT in the same web page (code behind). The asp.net form is a class and thus you can't (with ease) thread/call a routine in the forms code (and the forms life cycle will hurt you). So move the routine out (if not already - say to a static class). You can call it as a new thread from code behind. The long running code thus needs to be in a static class and not part of forms code. Start the thread in the form, but it must not wait (or join) to finish, since any wait in the form will lock up the post back until done.

Comment: can some help me with some example code and in details

Answer (score -2):

The main issue and problem is this:

```
await RunAsync(btn, num, int.Parse(Session["UserID"].ToString()));
```

So you block the code and telling it to wait until done? Why have bother to do all that work to setup a async call, and then throw away the benefits of that idea by THEN telling it to wait anyway? Calling somthing async is great, but callit with await and telling it to wait acheives ZERO here and in effect you not async at all by YOU telling it to wait.

Remember, on button click the whole web page goes up to server. Then your code behind starts running. Until  that code exits sub, then everything is blocked until that code is done and "returns". When the code is done (exit sub), then the web page is THEN sent back down to the browser.

So you can't tie up code behind since that ties up the web page sitting on the server. The button code has to occur fast. So,  you click, call the routine async (no await) and then the web page now can make the trip back down to the browser.

So, after all your wonderful efforts to setup that async call? You then blow the whole thing apart by using "await". That means your code is now back to waiting for the code to finish. In effect, you not async anymore. That web page is going to be stuck in that routine (and stuck server side).

You have to remove the await command, and you MUST let that code run through.

So, you have to remove await. You cannot block or have code behind wait, since if you do, then the web page is sitting server side, and no button clicks or anything client side can work.

It works like this:

```
Your button click.
    --> web page travels up to server)
    --> code behind starts running
    --> code behind WHEN DONE - exit subs
    --> web page travels back down to client side
    --> user (client side)  now gets a whole new fresh page with controls updated.

 Your code behind cannot WAIT or the web page is blocked
 Code behind can call routines async and that is ok, but without waits
```

So, your code behind cannot wait. You have to remove the await command, and that code has to run though and return.

Comment: after adding configure(false)  to the task it is working for parallel but sometims it is still doing time out from mysql , when I am checking show process on the my sql i can some queries are stuck and giving time out , i really do not know something i should fix on application or database

Comment: You either call the long running routine as async or you do not. You absolute must get rid of that await and allow the code to run through. You are free to call a external routine as async (this is good idea). You have to dump the await here - end of this story. As for some mysql timeout? Zero to do with this question and such timeouts will not help or fix or change anything in regards to a async call. So, I suppose we can talk about the best food for your cat, or about the weather? As such, that is a 100% separate question and separate issue and a 100% different and un-related topic.